# How to send "Customer Invoice" emails with Pay Later (pending status) gateway

Tags: woocommerce, email-notifications

I have created a new payment gateway plugin that allows customers to pay later. I will be using it with a woocommerce POS system.

I cannot get the 'customer invoice' email to send automatically - I believe it has something to do with the "pending" status of the order (which it must have in order to allow the customer to pay later). I have analysed many other answers but none have worked for me.

I have gently modified the code from this link (only - changed names and set up as plugin): https://github.com/creativelittledots/woocommerce-pay-later.

It uses a series of functions to trigger the email that I don't fully understand - but it doesn't seem to work: The default status is set to "on- hold" to allow the emails to trigger then the order is set to "pending" to allow the customer to pay for the order.

Here are the relevant snippets:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_order_status', array($this, 'default_order_status') );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string_find', array($this, 'order_status_format_string_find') );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string_replace', array($this, 'order_status_format_string_replace'), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending', array($this, 'send_pending_order_emails') );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment', array($this, 'valid_order_statuses_for_payment' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'wp', array($this, 'change_order_to_pending_on_order_received'), 8 );`

public function valid_order_statuses_for_payment($statuses, $order) {

    if( $order->is_pay_later ) {

        $statuses[] = 'on-hold';

    }

    return $statuses;

}

/**
 * Change the default order status to on-hold so that pending order emails can be triggered
 */
public function default_order_status($default) {

    if( ! is_admin() && WC()->session->set( 'chosen_payment_method') == $this->id ) {

        $default = 'on-hold';

    }

    return $default;

}

/**
 * Allow Order status to be accessible from emails
 */
public function order_status_format_string_find( $find ) {

    $find['order-status'] = '{order_status}';

    return $find;

}

/**
 * Replace Order status in emails
 */
public function order_status_format_string_replace( $replace, $email ) {

    if( $email->object ) {

        $replace['order-status'] = wc_get_order_status_name( $email->object->get_status() );

    }

    return $replace;

}

/**
 * Trigger pending order emails and invoice email
 */
public function send_pending_order_emails( $order_id ) {

    $emails = new WC_Emails();

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $emails->customer_invoice( $order_id );

    $emails->emails['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order_id );

    $order->set_payment_method( $this );

}

/**
 * WC Shop As Customer support on Order Received, because the default status is on hold we need to change these orders to pending
 */
public function change_order_to_pending_on_order_received() {

    if( class_exists('WC_Shop_As_Customer') && ! empty( $_GET['order_on_behalf'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['key'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['send_invoice'] ) ) {

        global $wp;

        if ( ! isset( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) )
            return;

        // Bail if we're not shopping-as - don't display the special interface.
        if ( ! WC_Shop_As_Customer::get_original_user() )
            return;

        $order_id = $wp->query_vars['order-received'];
        if ( ! empty( $order_id ) ) {

            $order = new WC_Order( absint( $order_id) );

            $order->update_status( 'pending' );

        }

        unset( $_GET['send_invoice'] );

    }

}
```

I also read that woocommerce_order_status_pending may not trigger emails so I have tried adding this code (no successes):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'filter_woocommerce_email_actions' );
function filter_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_pending';
    return $actions;
}
```

I suspect either:

1. The code to put the order 'on hold' then trigger then back to 'pending' is not set up correctly
2. woocommerce_order_status_pending hook does not trigger emails

I have a little work around to trigger from the "woocommerce_thankyou" hook in functions.php but I believe that this should be done in the gateway (plus I don't want to rely on woocommerce_thankyou - this email should be based on order creation).

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: You can trigger an email notification from any order status change in Woocommerce programmatically targeting a specific payment gateway…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec can you explain how I do that?

Comment: You should try to use [**`woocommerce_order_status_changed`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#306) where you can target the source status and/or changed status… Then with `WC()->mailer()->get_emails()` you can target the email notification that you want to send, like in [**this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48182905/3730754) … You can even target also your specific payment gateway

Comment: Thanks for your answer - unsuccessful though. Order_status_changed didn't trigger the email. Waiting for a plugin developer to see if there is a custom hook I can use.